# 複数のセルの文字列を合体させるか、正規化でこの文字が含まれている、と判断するスクリプトは組めませんか？

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

「（東京都）元ダミーデータ」のB列もしくはC列にある業種の情報を、業種以降を消して「現在実行した結果出力されるシート」のC1からC5、D11からD16までGASで入力させたいです。

画像のように、業種がB1とC1のどちらの列に存在するかわからないため、

- B1+C1で文字列を合体させてから、.replaceメソッドで業種以降を消す
- どちらに業種情報が入っているか判断するコード

いずれかの手法でスクリプトを組みたいのですが、方法がわかりません。

```
function Industry() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        let  v = i+11;
        //i はfor文の回数を決めて、セルのどの列に入力、出力するかを兼ねたもの
        //ｖは、データ整理の為決められたマスに入力するための変数
        spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('（東京都）元ダミーデータ'), true);
        spreadsheet.getRange('B' + i).activate();

        //ここでB+iとC+iの文字列を合体させたい

        spreadsheet.getRange('\'現在実行した結果出力されるシート\'!C' + i).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
        spreadsheet.getRange('\'現在実行した結果出力されるシート\'!D' + V).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
        //業種名をD1:D10と、D12:D22まで出力
    }
}
```

[今現在作っているシステムのダミーデータスプレッドシート](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aaRq1e033iiDsv580drnn-dxLNWDv-jP-DpliWQMnMs/edit#gid=0)

**元のデータ:**
[image: 元のデータ]

**実際にやりたいこと:**
[image: 実際にやりたいこと]

Comment: 現在の質問内容ですと、全ての仕様を満すコードの作成依頼のような形になってしまっています。
問題を分解し、一つの質問は単体の技術的な問いになるように工夫すると回答が得られ易いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
他の方が答えやすいように、回答を得られやすい形に工夫しなおしてみます